# Inserir sublista em lista C

Tags: c, lista

Olá, estou com dificuldades para trabalhar com sublistas encadeadas.

Gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta para inserir uma sublista em uma lista.

Declarei as listas da seguinte forma:

```
struct Casa
{
   int id_consumidor;
   int casa;
   float consumo;
   char *nome_consumidor;
   struct Casa *proxc;
}

typedef struct Casa house;

struct Rua
{
    int id_rua;
    char *nome_rua;
    house *head_casa;
    struct Rua *proxr;

}

typedef struct Rua street;

struct Bairro
{
int id_bairro;
char *nome_bairro;
street *head_rua;
struct Bairro *proxb;
}

typedef struct Bairro nhood;
```

Essa forma está correta? Como eu poderia fazer para inserir uma lista de casas dentro de uma lista de ruas e uma lista de ruas dentro de uma lista de bairros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como eu poderia fazer para inserir uma lista de casas dentro de uma lista de ruas

```
struct Casa *lista_de_casas = NULL;
struct Rua *exemplo1;
exemplo1 = calloc(1, sizeof *exemplo1); // nao esquecer de fazer #include <stdlib.h>
if (exemplo1 == NULL) /* erro */;
exemplo1->head_casa = lista_de_casas; // insere lista vazia
free(exemplo1);
```

> e [como eu poderia fazer para inserir] uma lista de ruas dentro de uma lista de bairros

Da mesma forma que em cima, mas com outras estruturas.